# Android ListAdapter, ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I want to know what is a `ListAdapter` and `ArrayAdapter`? Also, I am so confused about the fact that I can set a type `ListAdapter` to be constructed using `ArrayAdapter` as shown below.

```
ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>()
```

How can this be? How can a `ListAdapter` be constructed using the constructor of an `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: [`ListAdapter` is a Java interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). [`ArrayAdapter` is a Java class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) that implements that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListAdapter is an interface,see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

`BaseAdapter` is an class implemented `ListAdapter` interface,see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

And `ArrayAdapter` is subclass of `BaseAdapter`,see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html);

So we can write a code like this:

```
ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter();
```

Just like

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new A();//A implements OnClickListener interface
```